# prevent wrapping/stacking of columns in bootstrap when shrinking the size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to prevent the stacking of col-md-8 on col-md-4 using "nowrap" or any other alternative in the same way i did for the  (Unordered list).

Below is my snippet and i have also mentioned the classes of each box with colors.

Thank you.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
  #outside-container {
    border: 2px solid red;
    height: 500px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  #container1 {
    border: 2px solid green;
    height: 300px;
  }
  #colmd8 {
    border: 2px solid yellow;
    height: 400px;
  }
  #row1 {
    border: 2px solid pink;
  }
  #list1 {
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  #container2 {
    border: 2px solid navy;
    height: 300px;
  }
  li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  ul {
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  #col4 {
    border: 2px groove darksalmon;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid" id="outside-container">
    <div class="col-md-8" id="colmd8">colmd8
      <div class="container-fluid" id="container1">container1
        <div class="row" id="row1">row1
          <ul class="col-md-12 list-inline" id="colmd3" style="list-style: none">
            <li id="list1">
              <a href="#"></a>
            </li>
            <li id="list1">
              <a href="#"></a>
            </li>
            <li id="list1">
              <a href="#"></a>
            </li>
            <li id="list1">
              <a href="#"></a>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" id="col4">colmd4
      <div class="container-fluid" id="container2">container2


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

[bootply](http://www.bootply.com/kOyetvHiZZ)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need to replace `col-md-8` with `col-xs-8` and `col-md-4` with `col-xs-4`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta class="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
  #outside-container {
    border: 2px solid red;
    height: 500px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  #container1 {
    border: 2px solid green;
    height: 300px;
  }
  #colmd8 {
    border: 2px solid yellow;
    height: 400px;
  }
  #row1 {
    border: 2px solid pink;
  }
  #list1 {
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  #container2 {
    border: 2px solid navy;
    height: 300px;
  }
  li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  ul {
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  #col4 {
    border: 2px groove darksalmon;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid" id="outside-container">
    <div class="col-xs-8" id="colmd8">colmd8
      <div class="container-fluid" id="container1">container1
        <div class="row" id="row1">row1
          <ul class="col-md-12 list-inline" id="colmd3" style="list-style: none">
            <li id="list1">
              <a href="#"></a>
            </li>
            <li id="list1">
              <a href="#"></a>
            </li>
            <li id="list1">
              <a href="#"></a>
            </li>
            <li id="list1">
              <a href="#"></a>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4" id="col4">colmd4
      <div class="container-fluid" id="container2">container2


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 28):

The `flex-nowrap` class on the `row` worked for me in 2020:

```
<form class="row flex-nowrap">
...
</form>
```

Ref: [Bootstrap 4 - no column wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43517536/bootstrap-4-no-column-wrapping/43517835)

Comment: works for me in 2023, bootstrapv5.1

Answer (score 7):

With bootstrap you want to develop using the smallest device in mind first. This means to use `xs` on your columns. If you change `md` to `xs` your columns should no longer wrap on a smaller device:

[bootply](http://www.bootply.com/NGGSHJX70I)

This is an excerpt from [bootstrap grid documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

> Don't want your columns to simply stack in smaller devices? Use the extra small and medium device grid classes by adding .col-xs-* .col-md-* to your columns. See the example below for a better idea of how it all works.

Meaning you can combine media queries together such as `.col-xs-12 .col-md-8`