# Bootstrap 4 - no column wrapping

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I need to to prevent B4 columns from wrapping when resizing the Browser. Here is my code:

```
<div class="card card-outline-primary">
<div class="card-block">
    <form class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4" style="border:solid;border-color:red;border-width:5px;">
            <label for="visualTheme" class="control-label">1234</label>
            <div>
                <input class="form-control" style="height:30px;"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4" style="border:solid;border-color:blue;border-width:5px;">
            <label class="control-label">5678</label>
            <div>
                <input class="form-control" style="height:30px;" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4" style="border:solid;border-color:green;border-width:5px;">
            <label class="control-label">abcd</label>
            <div>
                <input class="form-control" style="height:30px;" />
            </div>
        </div>
     </form>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qnuogLgk/1/)

But it still wraps when I make it smaller.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: By "wrapping" you mean the way they start to "stack" at lower sizes...one on top of the other?

Comment: What is your exact requirment?

Comment: @mayersdesign - Yes. My requirement is to show a horizontal bar as soon as a column on the right goes out of a view. Another words, turn off responsiveness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`col-xs-*` **class is not supported in bootstrap 4** .`col-xs-*` **was used in bootstrap 3**  **So, Its replacement** in bootstrap 4 is `col-*`.

So your class `col-xs-4` is not going to work with bootstrap 4. So use `col-4` instead.

> Here is the code with your code.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card card-outline-primary">
  <div class="card-block">
    <form class="row">
      <div class="col-4" style="border:solid;border-color:red;border-width:5px;">
        <label for="visualTheme" class="control-label">1234</label>
        <div>
          <input class="form-control" style="height:30px;" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4" style="border:solid;border-color:blue;border-width:5px;">
        <label class="control-label">5678</label>
        <div>
          <input class="form-control" style="height:30px;" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4" style="border:solid;border-color:green;border-width:5px;">
        <label class="control-label">abcd</label>
        <div>
          <input class="form-control" style="height:30px;" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: I see. Yes, it's not wrapping columns anymore. But the columns get less width when I resize horizontally. That's not what I want. I want a horizontal bar instead. Any idea?

Comment: are you talking about the space left and right ,space inside the columns?

Comment: Space inside of the columns, another words their width. Is it possible to keep it unchanged when making Browser smaller?

Comment: actually its not possible as this  is how responsive design work.. If you want to fix there size that will be a custom code..

Comment: I think specifying a min width for columns should help. Is there a way of overriding B4 columns globally?

Comment: you can download a custom css  from bootstrap 4 according to your requirement. http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: No, I meant inside of my application without changing B4 base classes.

Answer (score 20):

The accepted answer doesn't provide a solution to the posters question.

Bootstrap 4 .rows are flex containers and the .col's in the row are the flex items. There are a bunch of utility classes that they provide to control the flex containers and items.

To prevent the columns in your row from stacking add the .flex-nowrap class to your row:

```
<form class="row flex-nowrap">
...
</form>
```

Reference:  [Bootstrap 4 - Flex Doc's](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/)

Comment: Dear Sir, in that year(2017) bootstrap did not introduced flexbox approach yet, so in those days we uses custom code :)