# Boostrap 4 container, row, col with horizontal scrolling

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Is there a way for Bootstrap 4 to create a table like structure with 'container', 'row' and 'col' with a container that expands beyond the width of the page resulting in a horizontal scrolling area.

In the examples I have now the columns of the row are always wrapped to the next row when the area runs out of space which is not desirable for displaying tables.

Comment: what speaks against using [actual tables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/tables/)

Comment: Nothing but it causes the whole page to scroll. The header and footer of the page are responsive so they scroll out of view too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably what you're looking for is to stop the columns from wrapping, there was a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43517536/bootstrap-4-no-column-wrapping/43517835)

Basically use a `row` with the class `.flex-nowrap`

I do agree with @cloned from the comment - to show data in a table format there is absolutely nothing wrong with using a table tag, bootstrap also helps you out with those: [table documentation from bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/tables/)

Comment: Yeah, almost. Now I get a table that expands outside the browsers view and the browser shows a horizontal (and vertical) slider. What I would like is a slider for just the table not the whole page

Comment: I think .table-responsive does what I need

Comment: Yep, you need both to get what I want .table-responsive on the outer div and .flex-nowrap on the .row div.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the example that works for me just fine. Very cool stuff.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div>
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <p>Dit is de content van de site</p>
    <div>
        <div class="table-responsive text-nowrap" >
            @for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                <div class="row flex-nowrap">
                    @for (int index = 0; index < 12; index++)
                    {
                        <div class="col">Column @index</div>
                    }
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```