# How can I make video size responsive with CSS Bootstrap grid?

Tags: html, css

I have a Bootstrap grid with three rows, and the middle one has two columns. In the first column I want to display a list of captions for the video and, in the other one, the video. I'm trying to have a fixed width for the left column (captions) and a responsive width in the right column (video), but haven't been able to. What I have right now is something like this:

**Full window size:**

Here the only content in the whole page is the video, which I did for simplicity and to isolate the problem in this question. I've added colored borders to some elements to better show the behavior I'm getting.

[image]

What I'm looking for is to have the video expand to a maximum of 120% of its width when there is space, and, when the window is shrinked, shrink with it, but only until it reaches 80% of its width. When this happens, I would like it to stay at that width and have the whole `div.container` overflow the page with `scroll`. I'll do my best to illustrate this with images and make sure I'm giving a good explanation.

**Full window size (not real, haven't accomplished):**

[image]

**Window shrunk (not real, haven't accomplished)**

[image]

This would be the minimum width, at which the whole content should start to overflow with `scroll`.

I don't need anything to shrink vertically, it can always overflow.

**HTML:**

```html
<body>
    <div class="container displayer-container">

      <div class="row top-row">
        <!-- Some content in the top row. -->
      </div>
      <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41943463/prevent-wrapping-stacking-of-columns-in-bootstrap-when-shrinking-the-size/41943639 -->
      <div class="row flex-nowrap mid-row">
        <div class="caps-container">
          <div class="cap-list">

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col player-container">
          <div class="video">
            <video controls>
              <source src="some_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row bottom-row">
        <!-- Some content in the bottom row.-->
      </div>

    </div>
  </body>
```

**CSS:**

```
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  /* background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30); */
  background-color: white;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 0% 1%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}



.mid-row {
 border: 1px solid green;
}

.caps-container {
  width: 550px;
  height: 550px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}






.player-container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
}

.video {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

video {
  min-width: 80%;
  max-width: 120%;
}
```

However, in full size, the size of the video is not `120%`, it's `100%`. And when I shrink the window, the video shrinks when all the surrounding divs reach it, and shrinks way past 80% and it also overflows all the divs, like this:

[image]

In short, I'm having two problems. One is making the video have the `min-width` and `max-width` I'm giving it, and the other is that it's overflowing it's container and all the ancestor containers. What makes it shrink is not the lack of available space in its parent container, but the lack of available space in the whole page.

I did my first try at this some time ago and managed to position the video the way I wanted using `position: absolute` for its container and `position: relative` for itself. But I ran into the same responsiveness problem and I'm trying again from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You can `vh` unit of measure to scale your containers relative to viewport's height and Bootstrap grid to do display the column on the width of the browser's window. You can learn more here:
https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/

The `.caps-container` fixed width can be done by overwriting flex value from Bootstrap `.col`. On the final style, you don't have to add `!important`, just keep the custom style after the Bootstrap one. In here it's the other way around.

**Take a look at this DEMO:**
The CSS is kept to a minimum to you can debug it easier.

```css
.top-row {
  height: 10vh;
}
.bottom-row {
  height: 10vh;
}
.caps-container,
.player-container {
  height: 80vh;
}
.caps-container {
  flex: 0 0 300px !important; /* fixed width */
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.cap-list {
  height: 300vh; /* scroll test */
}
.video {
  max-width: 150vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
video {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid displayer-container">

  <div class="row bg-dark bg-opacity-10 text-center p-3 top-row">
    <!-- Some content in the top row. -->
  </div>
  <div class="row mid-row">
    <div class="col bg-dark bg-opacity-25 caps-container">
      <div class="cap-list py-3">
        <h5>Scrollable Cap List</h5> 
        <p>Vestibulum lacinia ligula tincidunt leo vehicula vulputate. Nullam maximus vestibulum felis. Ut nec egestas est. Cras vestibulum, lorem nec consectetur molestie, augue magna mollis metus, sed varius elit orci a mauris. Vestibulum at risus at magna malesuada ornare id et elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col py-3 player-container">
      <div class="video">
        <video controls>
          <source src="some_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row bg-dark bg-opacity-10 text-center p-3 bottom-row">
    <!-- Some content in the bottom row.-->
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This works great to avoid the overflowing of the `<video>`. I hadn't used `width: 100%` on the `<video>` because it could be too small and the available space too big to stretch it that much. I'm trying with it again and I don't get the overflow, but I'm still not able to apply the `min-width` to it. Why do the `min-width` and `max-width` not apply here? How can I accomplish that? I'd like it to stop shrinking when it reaches `80%` and make the whole page overflow with `scroll`.

Comment: Why do you need min and max width? Just use the parent container. This is why I've added `width: 100%;`.

Comment: Right. Do you mean controlling the `max-width` and `min-width` of the parent container instead of those of the `<video>`? I need to control the size of the video so it doesn't stretch too much if it's small, and so it doesn't become too small when shrinking a lot. Actually, I had been thinking about using `.ajax` to send the intrinsic size of the video to the browser and then applying `min-width` and `max-width` to the parent with JavaScript. Does that sound like something reasonable?

Comment: For `max-width`, I think it's ok because you don't want the video to become too large and not have enough room at the bottom. You should give these value in pixels  or other unit of measure. But not percent, because it won't do what you hope.

Comment: For `min-width`, if the container gets smaller so will the video. And that's ok.

Comment: Can you try this? `.video { max-width: 150vh; margin: 0 auto; }`

Comment: If the viewports height is smaller, it helps so the video doesn't go over `.bottom-row`.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that originally. I'm testing right now in a 15" screen and it went over it, but that fixed it. And sorry, I confused some things, I'd get the intrinsic size of the video with plain JavaScript and then apply `min-width` and `max-width` to the parent. `min-width` is because [this happens](https://imgur.com/a/3uuI5Dd), and I'd like the video to not get that small. Is there a better way to do this? Or it doesn't make much sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237767/discussion-between-sebastian-tibichi-and-thesprinter).